# Strange return behaviour in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I have a tree node class like this:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(char _value);
    ~Node();

    char getValue() const;
    Node* getParent() const;
    void addChild(Node* _child);
    bool isLeaf() const;
    bool isRoot() const;
    bool hasChild(char _value) const;
private:
    vector<Node*> children;
    char value;
    Node* parent;
};
```

And  I have a serach method implemented:

```
bool Node::hasChild(char _value) const
{
    if (value == _value)
        return true;

    for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it != NULL)
        {
            (*it)->hasChild(_value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, the *tmp* variable is always false. If I trace it with a debugger, the `return true;` part executes, but the recursion continues. Any tips?

```
Node* root = new Node();
Node* a = new Node('a');
Node* c = new Node('c');

root->addChild(a);
root->addChild(c);

bool tmp = root->hasChild('a');
```

Comment: I expect any good compiler to emit a warning for reaching the end of the non-void function without any return at the end -- signaling part of the issue. Check if your does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in `hasChild` In the way it calls itself:

```
(*it)->hasChild(_value);
```

You *call* it but do not do anything with the return value. You may want to try returning the result.

Since it appears your algorithm indicates a non-sorted tree, that's not as easy as just prefixing the statement with `return`. You probably need to check for true and return it but false means keep looking:

```
if ((*it)->hasChild(_value))
    return true;
```

You also need to return false at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, now that I see the solution, it was quite simple. For any people who stumble on this question in the future, here is the code working: http://pastebin.com/R37EEnwn

Answer (score 4):

Your code for `hasChild` has two major flaws, it is never able to return false, and the return value of your call to `hasChild` at the following lines is never utilised:

```
(*it)->hasChild(_value);
```

This should resolve your issue (bar any issue with the rest of the code)